# Preventing event from executing consecutive times React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-hooks

I have this parent component that has this state which is an object, one of the properties is a function called onScrollbarSelection, that makes an axios post. All of this is going to be passed to the child component.

The child component uses an API from Highcharts, one of the properties ( afterSetExtremes ) of the API uses the onScrollbarSelection function from the parent (props). The problem is that afterSetExtremes can trigger a lot of consecutive times which is making the onScrollbarSelection function execute a lot of consecutive times as well and making a lot of axios posts, crashing the browser.

I've tried putting a timeout on the post call, but didn't work, it still calls makes the axios post a lot of times. How can I prevent from onScrollbarSelection (or the afterSetExtremes event) from executing a lot of consecutive times?

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [state,setState] = useState({
        onScrollbarSelection: (e) => {
            var min = new Date(e.min);
            var max = new Date(e.max);
            var minDate = min.getFullYear() + '-' + (min.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + min.getDate();
            var maxDate = max.getFullYear() + '-' + (max.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + max.getDate();
            async function postData() {
                axios.post('url',{
                    start_date: minDate,
                    end_date: maxDate,
                });
            }
            setTimeout(postData(),3000);
        }
    });

    useEffect( () => {
        async function fetchData() {
            var res = await axios.get(url);
            setState({
                ...state,
                data: res.data,
            });
        }
        fetchData();
    },[]);



   return(
        <div>
             <Child config={state}/>
        </div>
   )

};

const Child = (props) => {
    const state = {
        xAxis:{
            events: {
                afterSetExtremes: (e) => { //this triggers a lot of consecutive times
                    props.config.onScrollbarSelection(e);
                }
            }

        }, 
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} constructorType={'stockChart'} options={state} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the function with **debounce** effect.

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const [data, setDate] = React.useState(); 
  const [state, setState] = React.useState([]);
  
  const afterSetExtremes = React.useCallback(({ min, max }) => {
    setState([min, max]);
  }, []);
  /* create option for HighchartsReact */
  const option = React.useMemo(() => ({
    xAxis: {
      events: {
        afterSetExtremes,
      },
    },
  }), [afterSetExtremes]);
  /* get data from url end set it to data state */
  useEffect( () => {
    axios.get('url')
      .then((res) => {
        setDate(res.data);
      })
  },[]);
  /* do post if state changed, works with debounce 250ms */
  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = setTimeout(() => {
      const [minDate, maxDate] = state.map((value) => {
        const d = new Date(value);
        return `${d.getFullYear()}-${d.getMonth()}-${d.getDate()}`;
      });
      
      axios.post('url', { start_date: minDate, end_date: maxDate })
        .then((res) => {})
        .catch((error) => {});
    }, 250);
    
    return () => {
      /* if state changed in 250ms
       * clearTimeout remove handler
       * and axios.post does not call.
       */
      clearTimeout(handler);
    };
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <HighchartsReact
      highcharts={Highcharts}
      constructorType='stockChart'
      options={option}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me what methods I shall use and what debounce is. I really want a parent and child component though, can you just give me a little direction where I use the methods between parent and child?

Comment: Move `const option = useMemo(...);` to Child. Pass `afterSetExtremes` as a props to Child.

Comment: in events: { afterSetExtremes, }, you didn't pass any argument, how is that supposed to work? It doesn't execute. I did  events: (e) => { props.afterSetExtremes(e), }, and it didn't do anything also

Comment: `(e) => { props.afterSetExtremes(e)` - here you create new function which gets `e` and pass to `afterSetExtremes`. For what?. In `afterSetExtremes` I used destruction.
`const afterSetExtremes = useCallback(({ min, max }) => {/* use min, max */})`
the same
`const afterSetExtremes = useCallback((e) => {/* use e.min, e.max */})`

Comment: Yes I know destructuring, that's not the problem. The problem is the afterSetExtremes is an API event. (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes) , it doesn't execute anymore by following your logic, aren't you redeclaring it in the parent component?

Comment: Okay did it! The event triggering had to be like this: events: {
                afterSetExtremes:
                    props.afterSetExtremes                
            }. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to implement **setTimeout** and **clearInterval** into your **onScrollbarSelection** functionality. Like in the demo below, where wanted functions is triggered only once:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c0e9L6nf/

```
  xAxis: {
    events: {
      afterSetExtremes() {
        myStopFunction()
        myFunction()
      }
    }
  }
```

---

EDIT:

Here is a demo with reproduction of the above proposal using React: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-adeke4?file=index.js

Comment: didn't work, I think to use that some extra React steps would have to be done

Comment: @Anamoreira Not really, check my edit in the above post.